# Reading bytes from inputstream through serial port in java

Tags: java

I have a stream of bytes to be sent through a serial port. When all the bytes are sent I should receive a stream of bytes again through the inputstream.

**Output Byte Array**

```
byte[] command={(byte) 0xAA,0x55,0x05,0x00,0x55,(byte) 0xAA};
```

**Expected Response**

```
**Serial command received
Admin Mode - IR Learn
In IR Learner Mode
Press IR Key...**
```

**Actual Response**

```
**Serial command received
Admin Mode - IR Learn
In IR e - IR**
```

**InputStream**

```java
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    try {

        Thread.sleep(100);

    } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        int length = inputStream.available();
        readBuffer = new byte[length];

        Thread.sleep(110);


        while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);

            for (byte b : readBuffer) {

                sb.append(new String(new byte[]{b}));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Learned code : " + sb.toString(), "Code", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (IOException e4) {
        e4.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    readBuffer = null;
}
```

**OutputStream**

```
for (int i = 0; i < command.length; i++) {
    outputStream.write(command, 0, command.length);
    outputStream.flush();
}
```

How can I get the value without the repetition and `JOptionPane`?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of all the sleeps.
2. You're adding junk to the `StringBuffer.` Change this:

   ```
   while (inputStream.available() > 0) 
   {
       int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
       for (byte b:readBuffer)
       {
           sb.append(new String(new byte[] {b}));                                               
       }
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   while (inputStream.available() > 0) 
   {
       int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
       if (numBytes < 0)
           break;
       sb.append(new String(readBuffer, 0, numBytes));
   }
   ```
3. On the output side, you're writing every command several times. Change this:

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<command.length;i++)
   {
       outputStream.write(command,0,command.length);
       outputStream.flush();
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   outputStream.write(command,0,command.length);
   outputStream.flush();
   ```

Comment: For inputstream i am only getting the value as **serial** and not the full value

Comment: How can i get the complete value

Comment: What **serial**? Who is sending that? I suspect you aren't sending the right stuff here.

Comment: Im sending bytes as byte[] command={(byte) 0xAA,0x55,0x05,0x00,0x55,(byte) 0xAA};. After all these bytes are sent i wil have to recieve a message  **Serial command received
Admin Mode - IR Learn
In IR Learner Mode
Press IR Key...** through serialport. But i am receiving only **Serial command received
Admin Mode - IR Learn
In IR e - IR**.  How to receive the expected message

Comment: You may not get it all on a single event. Maybe it arrives in two pieces? or more?

Comment: Is it possible to wait until all the input data are read and close the inputstream

Comment: Certainly, but probably not in the event model. Remove the event listener and just read. But that implies reading until end of stream, which isn't the same thing as reading one entire response. Are you sure you understand the difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90414/discussion-between-sup-and-ejp).